# Difference between a Power Plane and a Copper Fill?

Tags: pcb, layout, eaglecad

What is the (or is there a) practical difference between designating a layer of a printed circuit board as a power plane as compared making a polygon cover the layer and naming it the same as the power net? I'm thinking of EAGLE when I ask this question, but I think there are analogies in other ECAD tools. I know Sunstone Circuits CAM file seems to think of these concepts differently, but I'm not sure how or why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Eagle, but in other tools the difference has to do with how the gerbers are generated.

For a power plane, the gerbers will be generated as a negative image. The gerber file will indicate features for regions or shapes where copper should be **removed**.

For signal layers, the gerbers will indicte features for shapes where copper should be retained (not etched away).

This can have a big effect on the size of the gerber files. For a polygon on a signal layer, the gerber will usually include a long self-overlapping serpentine trace (or mesh of crossing traces) to fill the polygon area. This can lead to a very large gerber file.

In the days when gerbers were transferred to vendors over dial-up modems, it made a much bigger difference to reduce the size of the files.

There can also be a subtle difference in the actual generated boards, because the features (whether positive features in a polygon, or negative features on a plane layer) must be generated by actual apertures on a photoplotter tool, selected from a limited set of available shapes and sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you set the difference in Eagle, unless you mean the net class. The only difference for net classes is for rules in the DRC (and exclusion from the auto-router), for instance you can define specific spacing that you want to have between power traces (or planes/polygons) and other signals or a different minimum trace width.

I think it's a good idea to define the net classes, especially for more complex boards, the DRC is there to help so you may as well teach it how.

Answer (score 1):

A power plane is (generally) a layer with not traces in it. A copper fill is on layers with traces. They are very close. A trace over a power plane (i.e. in the layer above or below it) has an specific impedance. That is good for signal integrity. A trace over a fill is the same. But a trace that crosses over the fill at the place where traces are will have changing impedance which can result in reflections and other signal integrity issues.

Samuel is correct for Eagle.

Answer (score 0):

I have always considered them to be quite different: a power plane is treated as a continuous layer of copper (although it might have a small number of tracks and pads) whereas copper fill refers to an area on an tracked layer that is filled with copper and usually grounded or connected to a supply rail. They are treated differently by the Pulsonix PCB software that I use, and most PCB suppliers.